# Magento 2.2 : Setting an image in the template of custom theme

Tags: theme, phtml, magento2.2

I have the code below in `MyVendor/MyTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/advertisement.phtml`:

```
<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/ad2.jpg'); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/ad2.jpg'); ?>" />
```

The first line displays the url of the image properly, I can see the image when I open the url in another tab of my browser. However, the second line with `<img>` tag doesn't display the image (which is in `MyVendor/MyTheme/web/images/`).

I tried removing the cache files and deploy static content:

```
cd /var/www/html/MAGENTO_FOLDER
rm -rf var/cache/* var/di/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/*
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f -j 1 zh_Hans_CN en_US
```

Also, I noticed in Chrome Developer Tools that this attribute was added to the `<img>` tag: `style="display: none !important;"`, and I can't remove it in the developer tool.

How can I fix it ?

**ADDENDUM:**

My template is set in the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="advertisement" template="Magento_Theme::advertisement.phtml" after="-" />
        </container>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Here is the tree structure of my custom module:

```
├── Magento_Theme
│   ├── layout
│   │   └── default.xml
│   ├── layouts.xml
│   ├── page_layout
│   │   └── home_custom.xml
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── advertisement.phtml
│   └── web
│       └── css
│           └── source
│               └── _extend.less
├── media
│   └── preview.png
├── registration.php
├── theme.xml
└── web
    └── images
        ├── ad2.jpg
        ├── advertisement.png
        └── logo.svg
```

After digging, I tried with other pictures, also randomly taken from the Net and it worked, below is the list of pictures tried and their details:

```
NOT WORKING:
web/images/ad2.jpg:           JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 100x110, frames 3
web/images/advertisement.png: PNG image data, 921 x 381, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

This image is another example of image that can't be displayed from phtml:
http://www.webdo.tn/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/publicite1.jpg

```
WORKING:
web/images/logo.svg:          SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image
web/images/pulpitrock.jpg:    JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.02, aspect ratio, density 100x100, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 500x377, frames 3
```

Why does it work with some images and not with others ?

Comment: according to me image code is fine may be  any jquery or javascript file add inline style

Comment: Send me link of project.

Comment: i think you only  display advertisement banner after menu. Another way  you can use show Static Block in your layout. Your image problem will be solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `$this`, try using `$block`.

So it would be like `<img src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/ad2.jpg'); ?>" />`

Clear the cache again.

If this doesn't work, you should check the css of your container which is holding your img element.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It still doesn't work using $block instead of $this. I updated my question to show the container I'm using.

Comment: try this, <img src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Theme::images/ad2.jpg'); ?>" />

Comment: I get the same result, still with style="display: none !important;" in the img tag. Any other idea ?

Comment: Then I think, some css might be changing the display property of this particular img element. Check the "Inspect element" option in your browser and see what's the class of the container which is holding the img element. Check the css class definition and see if there is any rule written to make the style to display:none.

Comment: I couldn't see anything wrong in the CSS, I unchecked all the CSS I could at checking the element, but I still get the same result. I added the tree structure of my custom module, is the picture in the good folder ?

Comment: My test didn't work with two images randomly taken from the Net, but a third one worked. So the problem came from the images. Why some work and why some don't work ? I have updated my question with further details about the pictures.

Comment: My problem actually came from AdBlock, installed on Firefox and Chrome. After disabling it, everything works fine.